# Move integration with Microsoft Teams to a different Business plan

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

I've configured an integration with Microsoft Teams vs Stack Overflow.

Now I've purchased a Business plan for another Team on Stack Overflow and I'll want to remove the pre-integration with MS Teams.
The connector manages the old Teams on Stack.

It's possible to point the connector with the "new" Stack Team where I've the Business Plan?